# How to configure PyCharm to install packages as sudo?

Tags: pycharm, google-cloud-storage

We are attempting to install "cloudstorage" as per [this Google documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/googlecloudstorageclient/read-write-to-cloud-storage). PyCharm is giving a permission denied error when trying to install the package.

When we look at what command was executed to install the package, it says "pip install cloudstorage". We noticed that if we execute that command in terminal - we get a permission denied error unless we run it as sudo. This leads us to believe that we need to configure PyCharm to add sudo in front of the command it is running.

We have been unsuccessfully on the web or SO searching on PyCharm and sudo and install. We have just found documentation on installing packages but haven't seen how to do a "sudo pip install cloudstorage."

How do we configure PyCharm to attempt a "sudo pip install cloudstorage" to try to prevent this permissions error?

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, there's no way to run PyCharm as a normal user, but use sudo (or enter the root password) only when installing packages.

If you're getting permission errors, I suspect you installed PyCharm itself as root (in, say, `/usr/local/bin`, or `/opt` or something). In that case, you can run PyCharm as root (`sudo pycharm` if you added the command-line link when prompted during installation), and then you can install your package, and switch back to your regular user afterwards.

There's a chance some of your home directory files will end up owned by root if you do this, though. It's fixable (`chown -R yourname.yourgroup ~`, or find specific root-owned files with `find ~ ! -user yourname`, and then `chown` any files PyCharm changed).

A better solution is to set up virtual environments, per the [PyCharm instructions](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html#configuring-venv).